# Why quotes are retained in string variables when surrounded by single quotes?

Tags: bash, quoting, string

I needed to retain the double quotes around a string variable defined in `bash` in order to be able to pass it to a dialect of the `Scheme` programming language. My question is why are the double quotes retained when placed inside another set of single quotes? In order to illustrate this I give some examples from my `bash command prompt`:

```
$ str1=hey
$ echo $str1
hey
$ str2="hey"
$ echo $str2
hey
$ str3='hey'
$ echo $str3
hey
$ str4='"hey"'
$ echo $str4
"hey"
$ str5="'hey'"
$ echo $str5
'hey'
$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single-quoted string will retain the string as a literal. A double-quoted string will retain the string with variable interpolation and expansion. This is explained in the bash man page - see the section titled QUOTING

> There are three quoting mechanisms: the escape character, single
>   quotes, and double quotes.
>
> A non-quoted backslash (\) is the escape character. It preserves the
>   literal value of the next character that follows, with the exception
>   of {newline}. If a \{newline} pair appears, and the backslash is not
>   itself quoted, the \{newline} is treated as a line continuation (that
>   is, it is removed from the input stream and effectively ignored).
>
> **Enclosing characters in single quotes preserves the literal value of
>   each character within the quotes.** A single quote may not occur between
>   single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.
>
> **Enclosing characters in double quotes preserves the literal value of
>   all characters within the quotes, with the exception of $, `, \, and,
>   when history expansion is enabled, !. The characters $ and ` retain
>   their special meaning within double quotes.**  The backslash retains its
>   special meaning only when followed by one of the following characters:
>   $, `, ", \, or {newline}. A double quote may be quoted within double
>   quotes by preceding it with a backslash. If enabled, history expansion
>   will be performed unless an ! appearing in double quotes is escaped
>   using a backslash. The backslash preceding the ! is not removed.

Comment: Actually I am a bit rusty on the concept of strings, can you point me to a good source? For example I am not exactly sure what does `string literal` mean. Furthermore, I did not understand the exceptional case when there is a newline pair, can you elaborate on that a little please?

Comment: @Vesnog a _string literal_ is simply a string that is printed, assigned, and used as a sequence of characters ("literally as written"). `A=fish; B='$A car'` would assign six characters to `B`, starting with a dollar sign. `A=fish; B="$A car"` would assign eight characters to `B`, starting with the letter `f`.

Answer (score 1):

See [the section on quoting in the Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Quoting).

Basically, enclosing characters within single or double quotes turns them into literal characters, with no special meaning (there are a few exception for double quotes but they don't matter here). So in the character sequence `'"hey"'`, the single quotes "protect" all the other characters, and the double quotes lose their special meaning and are preserved as literal characters.